# How much more RAM can I add to my Mid 2007 24" iMac?

Tags: imac, memory

I have a "vintage" iMac with the spec below:

[image]

This is going to sound like a real beginners question but can I up the RAM anymore? At the time, I upped it to as far as I could but could I put say 2 4gb RAM in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Low End Mac's [specs page](http://lowendmac.com/2007/imac-mid-2007/) You've already got it maxed out.

Comment: Ok thanks, I've seen stuff since that suggests it's maxed out.